# Angular, merge three arrays to one where id match

Tags: arrays, angularjs, api, merge

I got three API-endpoints, where api2 and api3 both got an foreign key matching api1 id.

For right now this is my code, doing what I want (connecting the objects with matching id into a new array), but I would like some help to get it cleaner:

```
$scope.arr = function() {
        $scope.cars = [];
        $scope.information = [];
        $scope.booking = [];
        $scope.newArr = [];

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '*api1*'}).success(function(data) {
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                $scope.cars.push(value);
            })

            $http({method: 'GET', url: '*api2*'}).success(function(data){
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                    $scope.information.push(value);
                })

                for(var i = 0, car; car = $scope.cars[i]; i++) {
                    for(var j = 0, information; information = $scope.information[j]; j++) {
                            if(car.id === information.carId){
                                $scope.newArr.push({
                                    "name" : car.name,
                                    "city": information.city,
                                    "mile": information.mile,
                                })
                            }
                    }
                }

                $http({method: 'GET', url: '*api3*'}).success(function(data){
                    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                        $scope.booking.push(value);
                    })

                    for(var i = 0, car; car = $scope.cars[i]; i++) {
                        for(var j = 0, booking; booking = $scope.booking[j]; j++) {
                                if(car.id === booking.carId){
                                    $scope.newArr.push({
                                        "book" : booking.isBookable,
                                    })
                                }
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }

$scope.arr();
```

It feels like a mess but the only way that I've succeeded with yet. Is there any other approach making this a whole lot easier?

Comment: Look into third party libraries, I use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#union)

Comment: Underscore or lodash are both good (_.union(), _.intersection() and so on)

Comment: I'll have a look at them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this in the last loop

```
for (var i=0;i<$scope.newArr.length;i++) {
                for (var j=0;j<$scope.booking.length;j++) {
                    if (newArr[i].id === $scope.booking[j].carId) {
                            $scope.newArr[i].id = $scope.booking[j].isBookable;
                    }
                }
            }
```